# How to wrap XML text content with XML tag in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I am traversing an xml document using w3c DOM and I need to wrap the substring of the text content inside an `org.w3c.dom.Element` with some tag based on some business logic.

For example, I want to turn

```
<title id="1">Java is a cool programming language</title>
```

into

```
<title id="1">Java is a <blah id="2">cool</blah> programming language</title>
```

I don't insist on using the w3c DOM library for my application so any suggestions are welcome in terms of other libraries that could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

All text in an XML document will be parsed by the parser.

But text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.

try this

```
<title id="1">Java is a <![CDATA[<blah id="2">cool</blah> ]]>programming language</title>
```

Comment: I would like to not resort to using character data in order to solve this problem.

Comment: While CDATA is a valid way of achieving this, I've always learned to avoid it. Could be a coding habit really; I'm not aware of hard proof or arguments against its use.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd use `&lt;` and `&gt;` (and others) to construct such tags in your node values. These are so called 'entity references. See for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) for some info about them; Google/Bing/YourFavouriteSearchEngine for more details.

In your example, this would mean you'd use:

```
<title id="1">Java is a &lt;blah id="2"&gt;cool&lt;/blah&gt; programming language</title>
```

Cheers,
Wim